# Can a user with Chatter Free or Identity user licenses be given permission for mutual authentication

Tags: authentication

Can a user with Chatter Free or Identity user
licenses be given permission for mutual authentication.

Comment: ok i'll bite, but what's with the profile photo of stacey irvine? :D

Comment: Lol, just cos cant put mine. PS m a chicken lover